# Is ACPI useful on a server?

Tags: acpi

Should I install acpi on ubuntu server? for potential power managing features?

I was thinking power down button would be useful for less terminal skilled users who don't know how to connect using SSH and shutdown with command.

what do you think?

what other things can I do with acpi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have `acpid` (note the "D" - ACPI Daemon, not ACPI tools; those are completely different packages!) installed just for the power button - I fear that after no response, a less-knowledgeable user might go for the ATX hard power off, which cannot be handled programatically.

Yes, it's a server, yes, *I* know what `shutdown` is for; however, I have no idea who will be managing the server in two years.

Comment: Hi, i installed acpi. But power down button doesn't work. is there anything I need to configure? I can't find folder /etc/acpi

Comment: @Sandro Dzneladze: You may have installed the wrong package: not `acpi`, but `acpid`.

Comment: @Sandro Dzneladze: Glad it helped. Edited the suggestion into the answer, it might help someone in the future.